# Padding в базе настроек

Tags: mysql, wordpress, settings, настройки, elementor

Есть страница (моя локальная) http://digitalelectronics.ru/wp-admin/post.php?post=7&action=elementor

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При просмотре она имеет адрес http://digitalelectronics.ru/elementor-7/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

База данных имеет следующие данные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
a:1:{s:7:"padding";a:6:{s:4:"unit";s:2:"px";s:3:"top";s:2:"40";s:5:"right";s:2:"40";s:6:"bottom";s:2:"40";s:4:"left";s:2:"40";s:8:"isLinked";b:1;}}
```

Как я понял эта запись задает padding блока, содержащего картинку-логотип.

1. Что конкретно означают переменные `a, b, s`?
2. И как в MySQL сохранить изменения данного поля (спрашиваю за разом - чтобы не делать резервную копию папки сайта, чтобы сразу сохранить удачно)?

Comment: 1. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.serialization.php

Comment: 2. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: Вы бы хоть немного пытались погуглить

Comment: И зачем вам второй аккаунт?